# Best practice for periodically listening for event while switching app with url scheme

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am completely new to Swift and iOS development, and I've come across a bit of a design crossroads.

I'm using a third party bank login service with my app, that I open with a url scheme. The url scheme opens the bank app, and I type my credentials, the bank app will then open my app again with my unique url scheme identifier, and AppDelegate will trigger this event.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

The bank api exposes an endpoint I can call to collect the status of the attempted login, if it was a success, I'll get some user information. Otherwise I'll get an appropriate error response.

Right now I am creating an NSTimer to call this collect every second, and check for its status. Which works fine, all fine and dandy.

```
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "collect:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I feel that this isn't that great of a solution since when the app switch to the bank app for authentication my app goes into the background thread, and the NSTimer event won't fire.

The question becomes, am I better of listening for the AppDelegate event for openURL in my LoginViewController, and when it happens start collecting the status of the authentication?

Is this a viable option, or even possible? or is the NSTimer considered a good solution?

Thanks in advance, I hope I'm making any sense.

Comment: You want to check user is logged in before your app becomes foreground via openurl event? Do I understand you correct?
Anyway, timer polling is never better a specific event, it consumes more energy and your app probably don't want to be a bad citizen. I would rely instead on app become foreground event + openurl event по launch the desired selector.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment. It's almost correct, I want to check if the user have logged in once my app becomes foreground again. So I think the delegate event is my best option then if you think it's the better alternative. 

I just didn't know if other classes like ViewControllers were able to, or should listen for AppDelegate events, because only AppDelegate can catch the events, if i understood the documentation right.

Thanks again!

Comment: any class may observe `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification. openURL is in appdelegate only, but you may forward it with any standard way - via notification center, for example, or calling a method of viewcontroller directly.

Comment: Ah ok, well in the openURL, I could check who's the source Application I guess, and if it's the bank application, I could maybe call the LoginViewController directly, that might work. Getting Notification center involved seems a bit unnecessary.

Write your comment above as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it would be better to call your viewcontroller's method directly in openURL event. No need in polling, since openURL gives you the correct answer, if I understand correctly.
Timer polling is always lose against a specific events, it's just an unnecessary energy consuming.